# Symfony2 validation of negative numbers

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm trying to add validation to latitude & longitude fields on a Synfony2 form. It should be pretty simple and I defined the validation.yml as follows

```
Acme\PictBundle\Entiti\Proxy
        longitude:
            - Min: { limit: -180 }
            - Max: { limit: 180 }
```

But that results in an input field like this

```
<input type="text" value="" pattern=".{4,3}" maxlength="3" name="acme_pictbundle_proxytype[longitude]" id="niwa_pictbundle_proxytype_longitude">
```

Because of the maxlength value I am unable to enter the values -179, 100.1 or 99.1. The entity annotates the property as a float (`@var float $longitude`) and the database has it as double and 1.1 is accepted so it's not that it thinks it needs to be an integer. How do I stop Symfony2 from adding the maxLength constraint to a number field?

Comment: Have you tried with `required => false` option?

Comment: Did you specifiy the type of the field in the form builder? I mean the second argument of the `add()` method.

Comment: Thanks elnur, I had to specifiy the field as 'number'. It's a pretty strange assumption on Symfony2's part that if define min and max values that it has to be a positive integer :/ If you submit what you said as an answer rather than a comment I'll mark it as correct.