# Symfony2: Preventing input in a money field is negative

Tags: php, symfony

I want to prevent negative values in a Symfony2 Formbuilder money field, but adding a Min(0) or Range(min=0) assert to the annotation of the attribute in the entity doesn't work. 
The attributes in the entity looks like this:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="integer")
 * @Assert\Type(type="integer", message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}.")
 * @Assert\Range( min = 0)
 * @var int
 */
private $price;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="setupFee", type="integer")
 * @Assert\Type(type="integer", message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}.")
 * @Assert\Range( min = 0)
 * @var int
 */
private $setupFee;
```

FormType looks like this:

```
    $builder->add('address', null, array('label' => 'Kunde:'))          
            ->add('productGroup', 'entity', array(
                'label'     => 'Produktkategorie:',
                'class'     => 'Ttm\AccountingBundle\Entity\ProductGroup',
                'property'  => 'name'
            ))
            ->add('dedicatedServer', 'entity', array(
                'label'     => 'Server:',
                'class'     => 'Ttm\ServerBundle\Entity\DedicatedServer',
                'property'  => 'labelname',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('dedicatedServer')
                        ->where('dedicatedServer.contract IS NULL');
                },
                'empty_data'    => null,
                'required'      => false,
            ))
            ->add('productDetails', 'textarea', array(
                    'label' => 'Produktdetails:',
                    'attr' => array('style' => 'width:350px',
                    'rows' => 4,)
            ))
            ->add('price', 'money', array(
                'label'     => 'Nettopreis:',
                'divisor'   => 100
            ))
            ->add('setupFee', 'money', array(
                'label'     => 'Einrichtungsgebühr:',
                'divisor'   => 100
            ))
```

Can anybody help pls?

Comment: First of all, do you really want "money" to be an integer? Look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html#required : "By default, all non-integer values (e.g. 6.78) will round down (e.g. 6)." == bad idea for money. Also, from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612834/symfony2-validation-of-negative-numbers it looks like "number" might force the integer to be positive

Comment: Yes i want to store input in the money field as cent value in the database. It works, but negative entries shouldn't be stored

Comment: `@Range(min = 0)` should work, can you please show us the code in which you use that constraint?

Comment: i added the asserts to the code, but this doesnt work, it stores negatives into the db

Answer (score 0):

For Symonfy3 try this yaml validation:

```yml
AppBundle\Entity\SomeEntity:
    properties:
        price:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - GreaterThanOrEqual:
                value: 0
```

`NotBlank: ~` makes the field required.